# OpenGL ES 2.0 Invalid drawable error

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to set up openGL for an iOS app I am building and I am receiving the following error:

```
-[EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:]: invalid drawable
```

Here is a part of my code, located within a UIViewController class:

```
@implementation MyViewController
{
    CAEAGLayer *_eaglLayer;
    EAGLContext *_context;
    GLuint _colorRenderBuffer;
}


+(Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

-(void)setup
{
    _eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.view.layer;
    _eaglLayer.opaque = YES;  

    EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
    [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the context current after creating it. I believe that does not happen automatically despite all the "magic" that some of these helper classes do for you.

```
_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: _context];
```

The first line is what you already have, the second line is the one you add.